# Why perform-method works, but other delayed_job's events not invoked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I included [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)-gem into my project:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'daemons'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'

# bash
bundle
rails generate delayed_job:active_record
rake db:migrate

rails g job MyFirstDelayedJob
```

And edited `app/jobs/my_first_delayed_job_job.rb` file like this:

```
class MyFirstDelayedJobJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args)
    JOB_LOGGER.info "perform() happened with args: #{args.inspect}"
  end

  def success(job)
    JOB_LOGGER.info "success() happened. Job object: #{job.inspect}"
  end

  def error(job, ex)
    JOB_LOGGER.info "error() happened. Job object: #{job.inspect}, Exception: #{ex.message}"
  end

  def failure(job)
    JOB_LOGGER.info "failure() happened. Job object: #{job.inspect}"
  end
end
```

Started delayed_job worker from rails console to see debug logs:

```
Delayed::Worker.new.start
```

Created rake task:

```
# lib/tasks/run_my_first_delayed_job.rake
desc 'Run job'
task my_first_delayed_job_job: :environment do
  JOB_LOGGER.info 'run_my_first_delayed_job.rake: Starting delayed job...'
  MyFirstDelayedJobJob.set(wait: 30.seconds).perform_later 'arg1', 'arg2', 333
  JOB_LOGGER.info 'run_my_first_delayed_job.rake: Finished.'
end
```

And executed in shell: `rake my_first_delayed_job_job`

After rake task executed, I have this logs:

```
# log/job.log
I, [2017-12-01T19:18:14.591918 #11664]  INFO -- : run_my_first_delayed_job.rake: Starting delayed job...
I, [2017-12-01T19:18:14.655178 #11664]  INFO -- : run_my_first_delayed_job.rake: Finished.
I, [2017-12-01T19:18:44.785494 #11591]  INFO -- : perform() happened with args: ["arg1", "arg2", 333]
```

Why `success`, `error`, `failure` callbacks not invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You creating new job like this:

```
MyFirstDelayedJobJob.set(wait: 30.seconds).perform_later 'arg1', 'arg2', 333
```

Your variant correct for [active-job](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html). But [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) gem adds `delay` method for running jobs, so you need use it, instead of `perform_later`. Rewrite your code like this:

```
# lib/tasks/run_my_first_delayed_job.rake
MyFirstDelayedJobJob.new.delay(run_at: 30.seconds.from_now).perform 'arg1', 'arg2', 333
```